# Система лайков и добавления в избранное, нужна помощь в реализации

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте!

Делаю тестовый проект "Каталог фильмов". Авторизация взята из коробки.
Выводится список всех фильмов; реализована возможность фильтрации по параметрам через Ajax запрос; вывод деталей фильма и возможность добавления рецензии.

Теперь необходимо реализовать возможность "лайкнуть" понравившийся фильм и добавить его в избранное, если пользователь залогинен, причем выбор надо где запомнить, чтобы в дальнейшем дать пользователю возможность "дизлайкнуть" и удалить из избранного.

Как это можно реализовать? Создать вручную промежуточную таблицу между юзер - фильмы, куда к существующим ключам (юзерId и фильмId) добавить 2 столбца - лайк и фейворит (bool?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно мыслите. Нужна таблица лайков.

```
public class Like {
   [Key] 
   [Column(Order=1)]
   public int UserId { get;set;}
   public virtual User User { get;set;}
   [Key]
   [Column(Order=2)]
   public int FilmId { get;set;}
   public virtual Film Film { get;set;}
   public DateTime DateTime { get;set; }
}
```

Добавил дату лайка, но можно и без неё.

И аналогичную таблицу для избранного, но тут уже наверное без даты.

Comment: если юзер поставит лайк на фильме, то в методе записать в эту таблицу 2 значения - id фильма и id юзера, если снова нажмет (дизлайкнет), то найти и удалить такую запись. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @e1ement точно!

Comment: описал 2 таких модели, пытаюсь добавить миграции и выдало ошибку Невозможно определить упорядочение составного первичного ключа для типа "MoviesApp.Models.Favourite". Это получается я не дописал связи к этой таблице от основных?

Comment: @e1ement там ещё нужно установить порядок колонок для составного ключа, сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: @e1ement добавил

Comment: подскажите, а надо добавлять public ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Favourite> Favourites { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; } в юзера и такое же в Movie?

Comment: @e1ement если вам нужно из юзера и из Movie получать эти данные, то добавляйте. В любом случае даже если добавите это не замедлит систему, так как они всё-равно будут Lazy возвращаться.

Comment: один момент - таблицы создались, но оказалось 3 столбца: UserId MovieId и User_Id. А откуда третий образовался? Модель не менял

Comment: @e1ement Если у ваших пользователей ключ `string` тогда такой столбец и надо делать.`public string UserId { get;set;}`

Comment: Мда... Спасибо. Авторизация же коробочная, я в нее и не смотрел.

Answer (score 1):

Делал похожий проект для курсовой.
Я тоже кстати буду такое реализовывать в будущем.
Я это вижу так.

1-Делать модель Лайкнутые;

2-Установить отношение один ко многим Пользователь => Лайкнутые.

Вы же в представление возвращаете список фильмов.
При построении списка проверять если данный фильм есть у пользователя в  Лайкнутых
то тогда html элементу который отвечает за визуальное отображение того что фильм лайкнут добавить css класс like(стили там  всякие красивые).

Предполагаю что элемент в виде сердечка должен быть ссылкой что бы при нажатии выполнять запрос на лайк или разлайк

что то типа такова

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Like", "Index", "Like", new {  id = тут_id_фильма }, 
new {@class=ТекущийПользователь.LikedFilms.Contains(film) ? "classLike" : "classNotLike"})
```

Из моих соображений film это элемент из перебираемой коллекции при генерации разметки для списка фильмов

Я лично все делал на angularjs там с этим попроще не много(лично по мне).

Comment: к сожалению Angular для меня еще темнее темного, спасибо

Comment: а не подскажете как правильно это реализовать? блок кода где у меня лайки и избранное выглядит так: <a href="#" title="Мне нравится"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>, метод public ActionResult Like(int id){var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();db.Likes.Add(new Like { UserId = userId, MovieId = id });db.SaveChanges();return PartialView();}